# How to get a consistent MongoDB backup for a single node setup

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I'm using MongoDB in a pretty simple setup and need a consistent backup strategy.  I found out the hard way that wrapping a `mongodump` in a lock/unlock is a bad idea.  Then I read that the `--oplog` option should be able to provide consistency without lock/unlock.  However, when I tried that, it said that I could only use the `--oplog` option on a "full dump."  I've poked around the docs and lots of articles but it still seems unclear on how to dump a mongo database from a single point in time.

For now I'm just going with a normal dump but I'm assuming that if there are writes during the dump it would make the backup not from a single point in time, correct?

`mongodump -h $MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_PORT -d $MONGO_DATABASE -o ./${EXPORT_FILE} -u backup -p password --authenticationDatabase admin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In production environment, MongoDB is typically deployed as replica set(s) to ensure redundancy and high availability.   There are a few options available for point in time backup if you are running a standalone mongod instance.

One option as you have mentioned is to do a mongodump with –oplog option.  However, this option is only available if you are running a replica set.  You can convert a standalone mongod instance to a single node replica set easily without adding any new replica set members.   Please check the following document for details.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/

This way, if there are writes while mongodump is running, they will be part of your backup.  Please see Point in Time Operation Using Oplogs section from the following link.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-databases-with-binary-database-dumps/#point-in-time-operation-using-oplogs

Be aware that using mongodump and mongorestore to back up and restore MongodDB can be slow.

File system snapshot is another option.  Information from the following link details two snapshot options for performing hot backup of MongoDB.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-databases-with-filesystem-snapshots/

You can also look into MongoDB backup service.
http://www.10gen.com/products/mongodb-backup-service

In addition, mongodump with oplog options does not work with single db/collection at this moment.  There are plans to implement the feature.  You can follow the ticket and vote for the feature under the More Actions button.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4273